# Struct defined in a function

Tags: struct, swift

I defined a struct in a function, no matter how many times I invoked the function, struct definition seems like always be the first time function invoked.

the code:

```
    var g = 0
    func f() {
        struct InnerStruct{
            static var attr:Int = g
        }
        println("static attr value is \(InnerStruct.attr), g is \(g)")
    }

    f()
    g++
    f()
    g++
    f()
```

the result is :

```
  static attr value is 0, g is 0
  static attr value is 0, g is 1
  static attr value is 0, g is 2
  Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I am not familiar with swift, can any body explain why?

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet illustrates the way the `static` attributes are initialized in Swift. It shows that `static` attributes are initialized only once, at the first invocation. Subsequent invocations do not "reassign" the value: you can see that incrementing `g` has no effect on the value of `attr`, which remains unchanged.

Comment: Thx, I think I get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply use instance of the struct and you get the desired result

```
var g = 0

func f() {
    struct InnerStruct{
        var attr:Int = g
    }
    println("static attr value is \(InnerStruct().attr), g is \(g)")
}

f()
g++
f()
g++
f()
```

result:

```
static attr value is 0, g is 0
static attr value is 1, g is 1
static attr value is 2, g is 2
```